# Vue.js - v-model with a predefined text

Tags: vue.js

I have an input attribute that I want to have text from a source and is two-way binded

```
// messages.html   

<input type="textarea" v-model="newMessage">

// messages.js

data () {
   newMessage: ''
},

props: {
   message: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
      default () {
         return {};
   }
}

// the message object has keys of id, text, and hashtag
```

I would like the initial value of input to be `message.text`. Would it be appropriate to do something like `newMessage: this.message.text`?

**EDIT**

I tried adding `:value="message.text"` in input but that didn't really show anything

Comment: Yes. That is how you would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can reference the props in the data function.

```
data(){
  return {
    newMessage: this.message.text
  }
}
```

Comment: if I were to submit the form, would the value remain of newMessage remain as this.message.text and not the edit I made? I'm using the initial value just as a placeholder text

Comment: @AlfieMcNarutoad The data function is called only once during the lifetime of the component, when it is created. By referencing the prop in the data function you are only *initializing* the data property. So the value submitted would be the current value of the input (the current value of newMessage).